# Is getElementByClass safe to use across browsers like getElementById?

Tags: javascript, dom

Is getElementByClass safe to use across browsers like getElementById?

**Update**
Currently using:

```
 window.opener.document.getElementById
```

But I want to reference the object by classname (there will be only 1 element with that classname).

Comment: If there is only one it would be more efficient to access it by ID because searching through the DOM for a specific class is not ideal but if you must i would recommend a framework like jQuery

Answer (score 9):

`getElementsByClassName` is unfortunately not reliable cross-browser. It's currently supported by the most recent versions of Firefox, Opera, Safari, and Chrome, but not at all in Internet Explorer or Konqueror, according to [Quirksmode](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_core.html#t11).

If you want to use it cross-browser, you'll have to have to provide your own implementation for those browsers that don't support it, [like in PPK's blog](http://www.quirksmode.org/blog/archives/2008/05/getelementsbycl.html):

```
function getElementsByClassName(node,classname) {
    if (node.getElementsByClassName)
        return node.getElementsByClassName(classname);
    else {
        // your custom function
    }
}
```

Comment: There has been a lot of work done by others on "// your custom function" already, so don't feel like you need to do it yourself. One specific example would be SizzleJS: http://sizzlejs.com/

Answer (score 2):

IIRC, `getElementsByClassName` was introduced in Firefox 3, Safari 3.1, and has been in Chrome since the beginning. I don't know if/when it was added to Opera, but it isn't present in Internet Explorer at all. (Though it can be added to IE8 by extending the DOM prototypes; see [Grant's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/900117/is-getelementbyclass-safe-to-use-across-browsers-like-getelementbyid/900187#900187).)

In other words, if you want a cross-browser `getElementsByClassName`, you'll either need to roll your own or use a framework.

Comment: Safari and Chrome both use WebKit as HTML rendering engine.

Comment: That's true but they use different Javascript engines.

Comment: @Gumbo — Sure, but what's that got to do with the price of tea in China? :-)

Answer (score 2):

As as been mentioned by others, `getElementsByClassName` is not available in Internet Explorer.

See the [Customizing the DOM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd282900.aspx#custom) section of [Document Object Model Prototypes, Part 1: Introduction](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd282900.aspx) for information on how to implement the functionality in IE.

Comment: It looks like this only works with IE8. You can't extend `Element.prototype` or `HTMLDocument.prototype` in IE6 (or, I believe, 7).

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to use it, you could test to verify if the object supports getElementsByClassname prior to using it and fall back to a JS implementation of the function if the browser doesn't support it.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using a wrapper library like prototype.js or jQuery, which both support a css selector model, and handle browser compatibility issues (IE6-7 being the bigger issues usually)

Comment: if it's loaded into the opener...  window.opener.$('...') works ;)