# "document.getElementByClass is not a function"

Tags: javascript

I am trying to run a function `onclick` of any button with `class="stopMusic"`. I'm getting an error in Firebug

> document.getElementByClass is not a function

Here is my code:

```
var stopMusicExt = document.getElementByClass("stopButton");
    stopButton.onclick = function() {
        var ta = document.getElementByClass("stopButton");
        document['player'].stopMusicExt(ta.value);
        ta.value = "";
    };
```

Comment: Check out this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/900117/is-getelementbyclass-safe-to-use-across-browsers-like-getelementbyid

Comment: Your function-name is missing an 's'.
In the accepted answer, the point around the missing 's' isn't that obvious. Hence commenting it here.

Answer (score 293, accepted):

You probably meant `document.getElementsByClassName()` (and then grabbing the first item off the resulting node list):

```
var stopMusicExt = document.getElementsByClassName("stopButton")[0];

stopButton.onclick = function() {
    var ta = document.getElementsByClassName("stopButton")[0];
    document['player'].stopMusicExt(ta.value);
    ta.value = "";
};
```

You may still get the error

> `document.getElementsByClassName` is not a function

in older browsers, though, in which case you can provide a fallback implementation if you need to support those older browsers.

Comment: Thanks , that makes sense.  Is the a function for selecting all classnames that is more browser compliant?  Or is it possible to select a range for the array nodes? (ie. 0-100)?

Comment: Not as a built-in implementation. You may need to use a library like Mootools or jQuery (which makes it super easy).

Comment: for a lighter-than-jQuery library to *just* do selections, you can use [Sizzle](http://sizzlejs.com/), which is what jQuery's selectors are based off of.

Comment: From http://caniuse.com/#feat=getelementsbyclassname, it looks like only IE8 doesn't have support for this method.

Comment: @tmeans: Yup, though that was a pretty big deal at the time this was posted.

Comment: @BoltClock Totally. Just thought I'd update for those in the future :)

Answer (score 26):

Before jumping into any further error checking please first check whether its

document.getElement**s**ByClassName() itself.

double check its getElement**s** and not getElement

Answer (score 15):

As others have said, you're not using the right function name and it doesn't exist univerally in all browsers.

If you need to do cross-browser fetching of anything other than an element with an id with `document.getElementById()`, then I would strongly suggest you get a library that supports CSS3 selectors across all browsers.  It will save you a massive amount of development time, testing and bug fixing.  The easiest thing to do is to just use [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) because it's so widely available, has excellent documentation, has free CDN access and has an excellent community of people behind it to answer questions.  If that seems like more than you need, then you can get [Sizzle](http://sizzlejs.com/) which is just a selector library (it's actually the selector engine inside of jQuery and others).  I've used it by itself in other projects and it's easy, productive and small.

If you want to select multiple nodes at once, you can do that many different ways.  If you give them all the same class, you can do that with:

```
var list = document.getElementsByClassName("myButton");
for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
    // list[i] is a node with the desired class name
}
```

and it will return a list of nodes that have that class name.

In Sizzle, it would be this:

```
var list = Sizzle(".myButton");
for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
    // list[i] is a node with the desired class name
}
```

In jQuery, it would be this:

```
$(".myButton").each(function(index, element) {
    // element is a node with the desired class name
});
```

In both Sizzle and jQuery, you can put multiple class names into the selector like this and use much more complicated and powerful selectors:

```
$(".myButton, .myInput, .homepage.gallery, #submitButton").each(function(index, element) {
    // element is a node that matches the selector
});
```

Comment: There seems to be extensive (universal?) support now for document.getElementsByClassName https://caniuse.com/#feat=getelementsbyclassname

Comment: @MatthewEvans - Yes, this is a 2011 answer.

Answer (score 12):

My solutions is:

- Change:

  ```
  document.getElementsByClassName('.className')
  ```
- To:

  ```
  document.querySelector('.className')
  ```

Comment: Agree, the querySelector method is supported by all major browsers while getElementById can be used if support for really old browsers is needed.

Answer (score 11):

It should be `getElementsByClassName`, and not `getElementByClass`. See this - https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.getElementsByClassName.

Note that some browsers/versions may not support this.

Answer (score 2):

you spelt it wrongly, it should be " getElementsByClassName ",

```
var objs = document.getElementsByClassName("stopButton");
var stopMusicExt = objs[0]; //retrieve the first node in the stack

//your remaining function goes down here.. 
document['player'].stopMusicExt(ta.value);
ta.value = "";
```

document.getElementsByClassName - returns a stack of nodes with more than one item, since CLASS attributes are used to assign to multiple objects...

Answer (score 2):

it should be `getElementsByClassName` NOT `getElementByClassName` ==> you missed `"s"` in `Elements`

```
const collectionItems = document.getElementsByClassName('.item');
```

Answer (score 1):

> `document.getElementByClass` is not a function

Yes, it is not a function nor method because it should be `document.getElementsByClassName`

Comment: I mean to say there was a spelling mistake

Answer (score 0):

`document.querySelectorAll` works pretty well and allows you to further narrow down your selection.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll

Answer (score 0):

The `getElementByClass` does not exists, probably you want to use `getElementsByClassName`. However you can use alternative approach (used in angular/vue/react... templates)

```js
function stop(ta) {
  console.log(ta.value) // document['player'].stopMusicExt(ta.value);
  ta.value='';
}
```

```html
<input type="button" onclick="stop(this)" class="stopMusic" value='Stop 1'>
<input type="button" onclick="stop(this)" class="stopMusic" value='Stop 2'>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
    enter code here
var stopMusicExt = document.getElementByClass("stopButton").value;
    stopButton.onclick = function() {
        var ta = document.getElementByClass("stopButton");
        document['player'].stopMusicExt(ta.value);
        ta.value = "";
    };


// .value will hold all data from class stopButton
```

Answer (score -1):

If you wrote this "getElementByClassName" then you will encounter with this error "document.getElementByClass is not a function" so to overcome that error just write "getElementsByClassName". Because it should be Elements not Element.

Comment: It has already been replied 8 years ago, you might want to check existing answers to prevent answering the same thing