# Chrome error, says 'no method 'getElementsByClass'

Tags: javascript, dom

I have the following line in my Javascript code

```
window.onload = function () { document.getElementsByClass("maintable")[0].width = "200%"; }
```

When I Try this, I get an error in Google Chrome saying "Uncaught TypeError: Object #{HTMLDocument} has no method 'getElementsByClass'" Can anyone tell me how to fix this?

Comment: When I type "getElementsByClass" into Google, the first result is [document.getElementsByClassName](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementsByClassName) from MDN. Don't even need to click the link to know the answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It should be `getElementsByClassName`, not `getElementsByClass`.

Answer (score 2):

Similar question [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7480496/javascript-getelementbyclass):

It should be `getElementsByClassName`:

```
window.onload = function () { document.getElementsByClassName("maintable")[0].width = "200%"; }
```