# How to animate a div once it comes into view using masonry and css?

Tags: javascript, css

Right now I have a page with divs organized in a grid using masonry.js.  I have that part working fine.  What I'm trying to do now is use a CSS effect to make the divs fade into view when scrolling down, simulating extended scrolling.

I'm following this tutorial http://tympanus.net/codrops/2013/07/02/loading-effects-for-grid-items-with-css-animations/ and even downloaded their zip to try to learn exactly how it works but I'm still having problems.

While I doubt this in itself will resolve the problem, one thing I did notice is in the script, it says document.getElementByID.  But my divs that I'm trying to apply this effect to are div classes and not div ID's.  What do I need to change in the script to get this working?

http://codepen.io/donnaloia/pen/aderB (note, in codepen, my grid is not aligned correctly for some reason but on my machine masonry is working fine)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.container').masonry({
   itemSelector: '.grid_4',
   isFitWidth: true,
   gutter: 8
  }).imagesLoaded(function() {
   $('.container').masonry('reloadItems');
  });

new AnimOnScroll( document.getElementById( '#grid_4' ), {
        minDuration : 0.4,
        maxDuration : 0.7,
        viewportFactor : 0.2
      } );

});
```

Comment: Keep in mind that when you're hotlinking to files on GitHub, like in your codepen, you need to link to rawgit.com -- so https://rawgit.com/desandro/masonry/master/dist/masonry.pkgd.min.js and https://rawgit.com/desandro/imagesloaded/master/imagesloaded.js.

And to target classes instead of divs, you could use https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementsByClassName.

Comment: Okay thank you, I made the changes to the js links.  The mozilla link you just posted doesn't work though.

Comment: I added getElementByClassName, and get error "undefined is not a function" on that line.

Comment: It's getElementsByClassName. note the plural. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7480496/javascript-getelementbyclass for an implementation.