# document.getElementByID and for loop

Tags: javascript, arrays, button, for-loop, getelementbyid

```
<button id="mybtn">click me for index </button>
```

My JavaScript code:

```
var myarray = [2,4,6,5,5];

(i=0; i<= myarray.length; i++){

   var allBtn = document.getElementByID("mybtn");

   document.body.appendChild(allBtn);
}
```

I want to make multiple buttons, so i have used for loop to create those. but it is not working.

Here is the url: http://jsbin.com/donafuluha/1/edit?html,js,console,output

Comment: The name of the function should be document.getElementById. Javascript is case sensitive.

Comment: Please explain more clearly what you are trying to do. What are the numbers in the array for?

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7480496/javascript-getelementbyclass

Comment: you can only have one ID in your page. You can have multiple class names.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make use of cloneNode in order to append existing elements

[Working Demo](http://jsbin.com/narahehapi/1/edit?html,js,console,output)

Code:

```
var myarray = [2,4,6,5,5];


for(var i=0; i< myarray.length; i++){

  var allBtn = document.getElementById("mybtn").cloneNode(true);

  document.body.appendChild(allBtn);

}
```

Comment: i<= myarray.length is not needed i< myarray.length is enough

Comment: @SagarSuryawanshi: Cool, just mark it as an answer if it helped.

Comment: Hey Vikas, I have added some additional functionality like on click of each button i will have its index. Please see the link. Please see the error is. http://jsbin.com/donafuluha/1/edit?html,js,console,output

Comment: @SagarSuryawanshi: here you are http://jsbin.com/duqeredadu/1/edit?html,js,console,output

Answer (score 0):

you can use cloneNode() to copy it and append multiple. I also recommend you remove the node from the DOM and only show the clones on the screen. And looking at your array it seems you want to attach some data too. This is done by either assigning a property or using *.setAttribute("name",value)*

```
var myarray = [2,4,6,5,5];
var proto = document.getElementById("mybtn");
proto.parentElement.removeChild(proto);

for(var i=0; i<myarray.length; i++){
    var allBtn = proto.cloneNode(true);
    allBtn.setAttribute("data-index", myarray[i]);
    document.body.appendChild(allBtn);
}
```

Comment: Yah! done it as per you comment. Thanks for valuable  suggesations. http://jsbin.com/xeficacoya/1/edit

Comment: also i have to ask, i can see in the jsbin u linked that u don't utilize the values inside the array. [2,4,6,5,5] what does these numbers mean?

Answer (score -1):

```
You should try following code snippet it will solve your problem 
    var myarray = [2,4,6,5,5];
    for(var i=0; i<= myarray.length; i++){
        var btn = document.createElement("BUTTON");
        var t = document.createTextNode("New Button"+(i+1));
        btn.appendChild(t);
        document.body.appendChild(btn);
      }
```

Comment: Why don't u just write btn.innerHTML = "New Button"+(i+1); ?

Comment: While this may answer the question it’s always a good idea to put some text in your answer to explain what you're doing. Read [how to write a good answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).