# Change all links of a particular class on page load

Tags: javascript

On [this](http://www.inspuratesystems.com/mandviwalla-motors/inventory/) site, all the links inside `inventory` class need to be changed to [this](http://www.inspuratesystems.com/mandviwalla-motors/contact/) link. I can't find the file to edit it and change the link so I am using JavaScript to do it. I have written the following code but it doesn't work.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
       document.getElementByClass("inventory").href="http://www.inspuratesystems.com/mandviwalla-motors/contact/"; 
</script>
```

Comment: do you have acces to jquery? or you want it to be only javascript

Comment: Post your markup too instead of providing link..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript getElementByClass](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7480496/javascript-getelementbyclass)

Comment: @lordkain: I can use jQuery. I just can't find the page template in WordPress which has the PHP file creating the listing.

Comment: do you have a link to the site of rendered html?

Comment: @RayonDabre: I want to change all of the elements from the list.

Comment: @lordkain: I have provided the link to the rendered html.

Comment: Try this: `var elems=document.getElementsByClassName("inventory");
for(var i=0;i<elems.length;i++)
{
elems[i].href="http://www.inspuratesystems.com/mandviwalla-motors/contact/";
}`

Comment: Do you only want to change links which have a inventory class.. Or do you want to change the links inside the div's with class inventory ? or ..

Comment: you also have a error on the page (index):1038

Answer (score 1):

Correct syntax:

```
document.getElementsByClassName("inventory")
```

if there's only one such link on webpage try accessing the first element as above method returns array of DOM objects

```
document.getElementsByClassName("inventory")[0].href
```

Answer (score 1):

It should be `getElementsByClassName` not `getElementByClass`(typo)

> It returns an array-like object of all child elements which have all of the given class names.

Try this:

```js
var elems = document.getElementsByClassName("inventory");
for (var i = 0; i < elems.length; i++) {
  elems[i].href = "http://www.inspuratesystems.com/mandviwalla-motors/contact/";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with Jquery

```css
$(document).ready(function () {
   $("#link").attr("href", "#someOtherPlace");
  });
```

```html
<a id="link" href="#somePlace">LINK</a>

<!--NOTICE THE HREF VALUE-->
```

Answer (score 0):

is it possible to use jquery ?
 try following

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$('.inventory').each(function(){
   $(this).attr('href' , 'http://www.inspuratesystems.com/mandviwalla-motors/contact/');
})

})
```

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/ov70gu96/  check the links after run the js i have just changed ur href to "mygivenurl"