# Unknown JavaScript Error - Function only runs first line of code

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have no idea why, but the function `thumbsScroll` only runs the first alert, and then stops. It doesn't even show the 2nd alert.

The function is supposed to hide the 'scroll' divs when the number of thumbs is less than 5.

Probably a very simple problem, but actually can't find a solution to this, and have spent a lot of time trying to find out. Is there something I'm not getting here?

```js
var mainImg = document.getElementById("main-image");

function thumb1() {
    mainImg.style.backgroundImage = "url('https://cml.sad.ukrd.com/image/394545.jpg')";
}
function thumb2() {
    mainImg.style.backgroundImage = "url('https://cml.sad.ukrd.com/image/572806.jpg')";
}
function thumb3() {
    mainImg.style.backgroundImage = "url('https://cml.sad.ukrd.com/image/486757.jpg')";
}
function thumb4() {
    mainImg.style.backgroundImage = "url('https://cml.sad.ukrd.com/image/612357.jpg')";
}
function thumb5() {
    mainImg.style.backgroundImage = "url('https://cml.sad.ukrd.com/image/612358.jpg')";
}
function thumb6() {
    mainImg.style.backgroundImage = "url('https://cml.sad.ukrd.com/image/661833.jpg')";
}

function thumbsScroll() {
  alert('test - function runs');
  var thumbs = document.getElementByClassName('image-thumb');
  var desktopThumbsScroll = document.getElementById('scroll-desktop');
  var mobileThumbsScroll = document.getElementById('scroll-mobile');
  alert('test alert 2 - doesnt work');
  if (thumbs.length < 5) {
    desktopThumbsScroll.style.display = 'none';
    mobileThumbsScroll.style.display = 'none';
    alert('if true')
  } else {alert('if false')}
}
thumbsScroll();
```

```css
/* rollovers */
#main-image {
  background-image: url('https://cml.sad.ukrd.com/image/661835.jpg');
}
#thumb1 { background-image: url('https://cml.sad.ukrd.com/image/394545.jpg') }
#thumb2 { background-image: url('https://cml.sad.ukrd.com/image/572806.jpg') }
#thumb3 { background-image: url('https://cml.sad.ukrd.com/image/486757.jpg') }
#thumb4 { background-image: url('https://cml.sad.ukrd.com/image/612357.jpg') }
#thumb5 { background-image: url('https://cml.sad.ukrd.com/image/612358.jpg') }
#thumb6 { background-image: url('https://cml.sad.ukrd.com/image/661833.jpg') }
/* rollovers */




* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: arial;
  line-height: 1.5em;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
#images-and-hook-container {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  float: left;
  background: cyan;
  display: flex; /* allows hook container to be full height */
}
#hook-container {
  background: blue;
  float: left;
  width: 40%;
  height: auto;
  padding: 3% 0 0 3%;
}
#images-wrap {
  width: 60%;
  height: auto;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
}
#scroll-desktop {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -6%;
  right: 5%;
  font-size: 0.5em;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  opacity: 0.5;
}
#scroll-desktop > span { font-size: 1.5em }
#scroll-mobile { display: none }
#main-image {
  width: 79%;
  float: left;
  background-size: cover !important;
  background-position: center center !important;
  height: auto;
  padding-bottom: 53.666%;
}
#image-thumbs {
  width: 19%;
  height: auto;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 2%;
  overflow-y: auto !important;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  height: 100%;
}
.image-thumb {
  margin-bottom: 6%;
  background-position: center center;
  background-size: cover;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  padding-bottom: 66.666%;
}
.image-thumb:last-of-type { margin-bottom: 0 }


@media (max-width: 768px) {
  
  body { background: red }
  
  #images-and-hook-container {
    flex-direction: column;
  }
  
  #images-wrap {
  position: static;
    width: 100%;
}
  #scroll-desktop { display: none }
  #scroll-mobile {
    display: block;
    background: yellow;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 0.5em;
  opacity: 0.5;
  }
  #scroll-mobile > span { font-size: 1.5em }
  #hook-container {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 3% 0;
  }
#main-image {
  width: 100%;
  padding-bottom: 66.666%;
  margin-bottom: 1%;
}
#image-thumbs {
  width: 100%;
  margin-left: 0;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
    overflow-x: scroll;
  overflow-y: hidden !important;
}
.image-thumb {
  float: left;
  margin-bottom: 6px;
    width: 24.333%;
    padding-bottom: 16.666%;
    flex: 0 0 24.333%;
  margin-left: 1%;
}
  .image-thumb:first-of-type { margin-left: 0 }

#aspect-ratio-wrap {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  padding-bottom: 16.666%;
  background: orange;
  position: relative;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  overflow-y: hidden;
}
  
}

@media (max-width: 400px) {
  #scroll-mobile { font-size: 0.25em }
  #scroll-mobile > span { font-size: 1em }
}

@media (min-width: 1000px) {
  #scroll-desktop {
    bottom: -5%;
    right: 6%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id='images-and-hook-container'>

<div id="images-wrap">
  <div id="main-image"></div>
  <div id='aspect-ratio-wrap'>
    <div id="image-thumbs">
      <div class="image-thumb" id="thumb1" onmouseover="thumb1()"></div>
      <div class="image-thumb" id="thumb2" onmouseover="thumb2()"></div>
      <div class="image-thumb" id="thumb3" onmouseover="thumb3()"></div>
      <div class="image-thumb" id="thumb4" onmouseover="thumb4()"></div>
      <div class="image-thumb" id="thumb5" onmouseover="thumb5()"></div>
      <div class="image-thumb" id="thumb6" onmouseover="thumb6()"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id='scroll-desktop'>Scroll <span>&#8595;</span></div>
</div>
  <div id='scroll-mobile'>Scroll <span>&rarr;</span></div>
  
  <div id='hook-container'>
    hook container
  </div>
  
</div>
```

Comment: `"Uncaught TypeError: document.getElementByClassName is not a function"` while running snippet... rather `document.getElementsByClassName` ? (with a 's' at Element)

Comment: Is there an error in the browser console? And what happens if you debug the code?

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["document.getElementByClass is not a function"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7480496/document-getelementbyclass-is-not-a-function)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should definitely keep your eye on the JavaScript console. This is the first place to look when something doesn't work. The console will try to give you hints about the errors in your code.

Memorize the shortcut, the console in chrome on windows: ctrl-shift-j.

When running your provided script the console will tell you that it didn't understand getElementByClassName:

[image: javascript console]

Comment: daft error on my point, sorry. I'll use the console I think as that sounds like a great idea for debugging. thanks for the advice

Comment: Every coder makes typing mistakes all the time, the art is to find a way to identify them fast. Your alert('test ...') did already a great job to identify the faulty line. You can also use console.log('test function') to print to the console, that's less intrusive since you don't have to click the alert every time (this makes alert almost unusable in a loop).

Comment: really great advice, thanks! I'll bear that in mind!

Answer (score 2):

You mis-typed

```
getElementByClassName
```

it should be

```
getElementsByClassName
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no a function like `getElementByClassName`. You can use `document.getElementsByClassName('image-thumb')` to achieve your goal.