# Javascript onChange with select/option

Tags: javascript

I have this javascript code:

```
 window.onload = function() {
                var eSelect = document.getElementByClassName('item');

                var body = document.getElementById('body');
                var face = document.getElementById('face');
                var neck = document.getElementById('neck');
                var feet = document.getElementById('feet');
                var hand = document.getElementById('hand');
                var other = document.getElementById('other');
                var pin = document.getElementById('pin');
                var color = document.getElementById('color');
                var bg = document.getElementById('bg');

                var optOtherReason = document.getElementById('myPeng');

                eSelect.onchange = function() {
                    //Do something
                }
            }
```

That code works if eSelect gets element by id. It won't work  if it is by class name, please help me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(*) getElementsByClassName()

(*) by class name you are getting a array of dom elements.

```
var eSelect = document.getElementsByClassName('item');
var len = eSelect.length;
for( var i=0; i<len; i++ ) {
   eSelect[i].onchange = function() {  };
}
```

Comment: That works but I have over 5 drop down lists and I want the onChange function to be for all of them not the first one

Answer (score 0):

May be you are using

```
document.getElementByClassName('yourclass');//wrong
```

**Correct Syntex:**

```
document.getElementsByClassName('yourclass');
```

More Info: ["document.getElementByClass is not a function"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7480496/javascript-getelementbyclass)

Note that some browsers/versions may not support this **getElementsByClassName** function [Check Details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/900117/is-getelementbyclass-safe-to-use-across-browsers-like-getelementbyid/900187#900187).

If you want onchange for all Select with class:

```
var eSelect = document.getElementsByClassName('test');
for(var i=0;i<eSelect.length;i++)
{
eSelect[i].onchange = function(){alert("sdfdsf");}
}
```

[<kbd>Demo</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/deepakmanwal/x93q2/)

Answer (score -1):

Try:

```
var eSelect = document.getElementByClassName('item')[0]
```

The suggested `getElementByClassName('item')` actually gives back an array of matching elements unlike getElementById that gives the matching element directly. So the `[0]` in suggested code selects the first and only element in that array.

Comment: getElementByClassName is not same as getElementsByClassName. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementsByClassName