# Change inner html not working

Tags: javascript, innerhtml

I am having a problem trying to change some `innerHtml` with this piece of code bellow:

```
var element = document.getElementByClass("productitemcell > a");
element.innerHTML = "Remover";
```

It is suposed to change the innerHTML from a link that says"Remove" to "Remover" and its not working.

Here's the page of it: http://ooleiro.businesscatalyst.com/OrderRetrievev2.aspx

You have to buy some products to access this shopping cart page.

Comment: Check this article - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/900117/is-getelementbyclass-safe-to-use-across-browsers-like-getelementbyid

Comment: I don't see any element with the class `productitemcell ` in your html

Comment: `getElementsByClass`

Comment: its on the shopping cart

Answer (score 3):

I think you meant `document.getElementsByClassName()`

This method will return a `HTMLCollection` object. You can grab the first element like so:

```
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('class');
var firstElement = elements[0];
```

Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName

Comment: It doenst  work too.

Answer (score 0):

The method is called `getElementsByClassName` (plural) and returns a collection of HTML elements. For which one of those do you want to change the HTML? For the first one?

Additionally, you cannot use a CSS selector like that in standard DOM methods

EDIT: Obviously you want to change all occurrences of `a` elements inside all occurrences of `.productitemcell`:

```
var pics = document.getElementsByClassName("productitemcell");
for(i=0; i<pics.length; i++) {
   // loop over all elements with that class
   var anchors = pics[i].getElementsByTagName("a");
   for(j=0; j<anchors.length; j++) {
      // loop over all anchor elements within the current class element
      anchors[j].innerHTML = 'Remover';
   }
}
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75407/discussion-on-answer-by-devnull69-change-inner-html-not-working).

Comment: Nevertheless ... my freelancer.com user name is the same as here

Answer (score 0):

Had to change the class to

```
var removerprod = document.getElementsByClassName("remover");
for(i=0; i<removerprod.length; i++) {
   // loop over all elements with that class
   var anchors = removerprod[i].getElementsByTagName("a");
   for(j=0; j<anchors.length; j++) {
      // loop over all anchor elements within the current class element
      anchors[j].innerHTML = 'Remover';
   }
}
```

so it doesnt change the product name as well. the only problem remaining is that it is retrieving with ajax and everytime it refreshes it changes again to "Remove"Thank's you devnul69, i realy learned a lot today about js.

Comment: You can put this code into a function and call this function every time your ajax code refreshes the elements. That way they would turn back to 'Remover' every time they refreshed

Comment: can that be onLoad.function(){"the code here"}?

Comment: More like `window.onload = function() {\\code from above goes here}`. It seems like you could use some basic Javascript coaching :-)

Comment: so to use the onload event to change ajax it has to be window and not document?

Comment: It depends on where your ajax code is and how you use it. Usually you'll already have (at least) one callback function which is called as soon as the ajax request returns. You'll have to put the call to the new function mentioned above into this callback